# Different MapKit Annotations

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have a map and want to display annotations for different POIs. I have a database where I load this data from via API, e.g. (Zoo, Starbucks, McDonalds). For each of this, I would create a class and all of these classes will adhere to MKAnnotation. They should look different by having a different picture on the map. So I think I would need different classes of MKAnnotation?

I am now thinking of how to efficiently make use of annotations. The workflow for me right now is:

1. Download Zoo Data (JSON)
2. Create Zoo Objects from JSON and keep these objects in an zoo array
3. Display map annotations by passing this array to mapkit

When I have now a second type of annotation:

1. Download Starbucks Data (JSON)
2. Create Starbucks Objects from JSON and keep these objects in a starbucks array
3. Display map annotations by passing this array to mapkit

But this seems inefficient to me. Wouldnt it be better to use only one array for all objects and use a property within each class to identify which object it is? Where do I check for the right annotation class to be loaded? Or is it only one annotation class that would be needed?

Comment: Can you explain your question more? with example if possible. I read it like three times but can't seem to get it

Comment: I was thinking of a way to show different kinds of annotations on the same map. So how do I distinguish between them so I can recognize which type of annotation I am handling (e.g. "taxi", "bus", "train"). Do i use properties on each class that will be displayed on the map?

Comment: by different kinds of annotations, what kind of difference are you talking about? how is the annotations for "taxi" and "bus" different?

Comment: How about adding type property to annotation class? e.g. `annotation.type = MyAnnotation.Zoo`